# Can't uninstall heroku or heroku-toolbelt on linux

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

When I run `sudo apt-get --purge remove heroku-toolbelt` or `sudo apt-get --purge remove heroku`

I just get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package heroku
```

and for toolbelt:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package heroku-toolbelt
```